# What's matter? NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

what's mean? `NameError: name 'make_blobs' is not defined` I don't understand... plz help..

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
X, y = make_blobs(random_state=1)
    
agg = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3)
assignment = agg.fit_predict(X)
    
mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], assignment)
plt.legend(["cluster 0", "cluster 1", "cluster 2"], loc="best")
plt.xlabel("feature 0")
plt.ylabel("feature 1")
```

Comment: If a method is from another package, you have to import it.   Add `from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs` at the top of your code.

Comment: Don't add unrelated tags to your question, this has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imported it yet. Use:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to use `sklearn.data_sets.make_blobs` ?
You should import that explicitly and use it appropriately.